# In what circumstance does IE8 repeat words(text) in multilines textboxes?

Tags: .net, asp.net, internet-explorer

This is a work question generalized so it can help other people with this nightmare. 
I deployed an ASP.net application on four PC Machines. This application asks them to enter data in many textboxes that are multiline as they LOVE to write. They are using IE8 with compatability mode that I have hardcoded into the httpheaders. The error I describe I have seen happen on their machines but not on mine.

The fields are contained in a tabContainer from AjaxControlToolkit. They have many textboxes, dropdownlists and a button to submit and save. Sometimes when they are writting the words at the end of the sentence repeat. Other times they repeat when they save.

My take on this is that it is most probably because of issues with overflow but I tested that out and it worked for a while and it broke again.

MainPage

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ShowAjaxError.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestForWhatever.ShowAjaxError" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<link href="css/ajaxproblem.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    <cc1:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" 
        Width="800px" Font-Size="Medium">
        <cc1:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="FooTab" ID="FooTab">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Foobar tab
            </HeaderTemplate>
         <ContentTemplate>

         <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server"  
                             Text="Comments:" Width="120px"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" CssClass="MultilineIssue" 
                             Height="101px" Wrap="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="223px"></asp:TextBox>                   
         <br />
         <br />
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

         </ContentTemplate>
         </cc1:TabPanel>
         </cc1:TabContainer>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
}

.MultilineIssue
{
 color: Black;
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:74.5%;
    text-align:left;
 border:1px #7f9db9 solid;
 overflow:auto;

}
```

Example input:

```
A gray Fox walks the land. A gray 
Fox walks the land. A gray Fox 
walks the land.
```

What the browser shows sometimes

```
A gray Fox walks the land. A gray 
gray Fox walks the land. A gray Fox 
Fox walks the land.
```

Keep in mind this repetition is not passed to the database.

I am sorry if this issue has already been asked I searched but couldn't find a synonym for word that didn't meant Microsoft Word. Google was no help either. Thank you for your help.

Comment: One potential synonym could be "token".

Comment: You realize you are in tough luck when Google returns this question as the first entry and all others talk about ruby and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had the same issue, since there were no solutions posted, here's what I found:

- When I had set Width="400", words would be repeated
- When I changed to Width="100%" (with the percentage sign), words were no longer repeated.

Comment: Interesting, in my case I had a space constraint but I can try to set the table cell width and so forth and set the textboxt to use the percent. I hope that IE 9 didn't break it further.

Comment: While 100% width gets rid of the repeating words, it breaks again if you add padding or box-sizing to size your textarea.

Comment: Though this is an old post, I had the same problem recently while dealing in IE8. I am simply adding to the existing answer here that the workaround could be `min-width:400px;` also. This takes care of the size of the textbox as well.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set width to 38em; this will also solve the issue. It solved in our case. :)